# Cannot connect to mail server with phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I try to open php mailer file to text it and it says this:

```
Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ()
Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to smtp.gmail.com:587 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Do you guys know how to fix it?

Comment: Can we see the code snippet? stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And make the effort to complete the 2-minute site tour as well.

Comment: And follow the link to documentation in the error message, and search before posting.

Comment: Please use for the next question are more meaningful title it was not clear at all what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn on *Access for less secure apps* for your gmail. Suggest to use a new e-mail to do it. Because it is less secure.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en